# There is no trusted URLs configured for the app deployment on Client side People Picker

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, sharepoint-hosted-app

I've built and been using a Sharepoint hosted app which uses a Client side people picker which all worked correctly until today. No when using them I get the following error.

> There is no trusted URLs configured for the app deployment.

I have made no code changes in the last week so can only assume there is an issue with SP2013 online? Anyone else seen this?

Comment: This part is still in your Manifest I guess? <AppPrincipal>
    <Internal AllowedRemoteHostUrl="~remoteAppUrl"/>
</AppPrincipal>

Comment: Yeah i have that in place...for Sharepoint hosted we use.

Comment: for Sharepoint hosted we use. <AppPrincipal>
    <Internal />
  </AppPrincipal>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Posterity the workaround to fix this is as follows.

```
// Old Method which gives the above error
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
// Workaround as suggested by Microsoft
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor("/");
```

This will get things back up and running again until Microsoft resolve the issue.

Regards,

S

UPDATE:
The lastest advice from MS is

'This is currently a known issue in the SPO environment and is being investigated and looked into. The work around you have to change the URL to lower case is mentioned and you can continue using it till a fix is applied.'

... the to lower-case workaround being:

```
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWebUrl.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

See following threads in Developing Apps for SharePoint 2013 forums

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8c9a9b06-e187-4174-8905-903d6b02b98c/there-is-no-trusted-urls-configured-for-the-app-deployment-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps?forum=appsforsharepoint

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b76988e-277c-4507-8828-216c8545ee6e/sharepoint-hosted-app-gives-there-is-no-trusted-urls-configured-for-the-app-deployment-error?forum=appsforsharepoint

Comment: Yip seems like an issue with SP and NOT my code...which is always good to hear...

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with some sample app code and came across this same issue, but mine is a little bit different:

```
var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appWebUrl.toLowerCase());
```

In any case, adding the toLowerCase() method allows the code to execute properly.